# Could not install gsutil with latest version

Tags: google-bigquery

I upgraded to the latest BQ (2.0.14) then downloaded the latest gsutil tar package and  manually updated gsutil thus:

"python setup.py install"

When I run gsutil I now get the following error message:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/gsutil", line 8, in 
    load_entry_point('gsutil==3.31', 'console_scripts', 'gsutil')()
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 318, in load_entry_point
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2221, in load_entry_point
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1954, in load
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gsutil-3.31-py2.7.egg/gslib/**main**.py", line 32, in 
    from gslib import util
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gsutil-3.31-py2.7.egg/gslib/util.py", line 28, in 
    from oauth2client.client import HAS_CRYPTO
ImportError: cannot import name HAS_CRYPTO

I couldn't find a way to actually uninstall gsutil so I'm stuck.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: if it's any consolation, I have the same issue.  I tried installing oauth2client 1.1 and it now fails `ImportError: No module named lifecycle`

Comment: BTW, I have tried this on native Windows and Cygwin, with the same result.

Comment: Update:  tried on Linux (same versions): worked fine.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried upgrading oauth2client?

```
pip install -U oauth2client
```